# Multiple Address In WP-Option Value

Tags: database, options, wp-config

I've tried to setup my wordpress using 1 domain name and 1 ip address, 
after this, all the css is missing, but the site still can be accessible using both domain and ip address.

[image]

[image]

Then I tried to revert back to either ip only or domain only, the css all became normal again

So is there any fix to get the css back to normal with 2 address set in wp_option?

Webserver : Nginx (I have tested for days, I can safe to say there is no problem with the webserver)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Fuxia. I don't think siteurl and home accept comma delimited values. Could you clarify why are your doing this? Perhaps others can recommend another way to achieve your goal.

Comment: @TedStresen-Reuter I am using wireguard VPN to secure my wordpress, instead of whitelist the VPN public ip on "wp-login.php", I think to allow the "internal ip" to access the "wp-login.php" is better so I don't need to route all my traffic to the VPN. Do you have any idea to make "siteurl" and "home" to accept multiple address?

Comment: @iwanttosleep you shouldn't be changing WP itself to get around the limitations of your VPN. Just make WP Admin/Login reject requests unless they come from a particular IP aka the exit node of your VPN. That can be done at the Apache/Nginx level. There's no reason that the URL of the site would ever change to be the IP

Comment: Although I agree you shouldn't be changing WP to get around a limitation of your connection method (it's not necessary, I don't think), you could try adding login in wp-settings.php that set's WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL thus achieving your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing for hours, finally get it done.

Here the solution:
In database `wp_options` change the value for `siteurl` and `home` from `your wordpress url` to `/path/to/wordpress`

**Wordpress URL**
[image]

**Path To Wordpress**
[image]

Then add these code in the bottom of `wp-config.php`

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' .$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' );
```

Now you can use Domain and IP together to access your wordpress. Of course you need to setup your webserver to listen to both

*It is not my VPN limitation though, just because I can and I think this is more cool.

Answer (score -1):

You can't put multiple addresses in those options fields, that's not how it works. Anything other than a single address will result in a broken site.

Out of the box, on a singular site, WP will serve pages to any address, the issue you face is that the URLs in the page source will all contain absolute URLs rather than relative URLs.

Instead, consider focusing on your actual problem that you mentioned in your comment, rather than how to implement a speculative solution, that of configuring your VPN